# Sometimes JWT returns 401 for valid token in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: .net-core, jwt

I am facing an interesting problem. I'm using **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer version 3.0.3** in a **.Net Core 3.0** application and interestingly, the requests *sometimes returns 401* without a logical reason. After logging the requests I see that `context.HttpContext?.User?.Claims` *is empty, but I can get the related token by typing* `context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]`.

I have readed the link below and i know there is vulnerability in this library but i don't think it's the reason of this stiuation.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/3.0.3

The services are running on docker. And this problem started to appear in the last 1 week and there was no update in the places related to the token. It redirects all requests to other servers through NGINX itself.
I thought NGINX causes the problem and i increased the `client_max_body_size` but it didn't work.

I can get successful results when I send the token I logged to the same service via Postman.

As a result I still couldn't find the problem

Below is JWT configurations

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = false;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi guys, I couldn't find the exact cause of the problem but I found a solution, a workaround.

As I mentioned above, since I can get the token from the header, I'm re-setting the token from the request header to the claims in a middleware.

Answer (score 1):

We face the same problem after long investigation we found our API deployed in 3 pods but according to un known reason each pod have time different to others so lets say
token expiry 60 minutes
first pod time : 1:00 AM
second pod time : 3:00 AM
third pod time : 5:00 AM
when the request go to first pod the pod create the token expired in 2:00 AM
the second request got to pod number 2or 3 so it is expired according to it

So once we synced datetime between all pods problem solved